# How to add database connection into eclipse?

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, toad

I'm working on dynamic web application using **Servlets and JSP** building a login page
i make everything but now i need to add **DB** to check if the user-name and password is true or false , i am using **toad** and have schema with table of User_info.
My question is how to connect my **DB** to my application?

Answer (score 0):

Toad itself isn't a database it's just administration software.

You'll probably want to use a JDBC driver plug in.

There's a pretty easy tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html) which shows you how to use it with Eclipse. You should be able to take the basics from there and apply it to your web application.

Comment: i got the answer :) 

the magic is in adding context.xml file in the META-INF directory , that is consider to have the information about your DB .

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context path="/The Product Name">

    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" maxActive="20"         
    maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/The Product Name" 
    username="schema userName" password="schema Password"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="Schema Url"
    validationQuery="select 1 from dual" />


    </Context>

Comment: Ok, well you may want to post it as an answer rather than a comment so that you can close the question off as answered later on. Cheers :)

Comment: i can't , only after 8 hours .Cheers :)